# Integração das informações de um Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service

Estou com um pouco de dificuldade para realizar a criação  de um **Web Service.**

Tenho um banco de dados **MySQL** simples para cadastro de pessoas.

Já tenho meus métodos para realizar operações **CRUD** prontos em uma `classe` .
que foram usados em uma aplicação `Windows Forms`

Quero que as minhas operações **CRUD** passem a funcionar a partir de solicitações por **Web service**.

Pelo que entendi posso publicar Web Service utilizando **IIS** , assim qualquer dispositivo que tenha meu endereço usando uma `rede local` pode acessar meu Web Service.

Para construir este tipo de funcionalidade estou pensando em migrar meus métodos e configuração de conexões para um  projeto do tipo  **ASP.NET Web Service Aplication**

Com um projeto com os métodos do tipo `[WebMethod]` devidamente
configurados vou poder usar os métodos em qualquer linguagem de
programação ?

Tenho conhecimento vago sobre web services , mas pelo o que eu entendi que o objetivo principal seria a integração das informações .

Meu objetivo com este projeto e divulgar um Web Service hospedado em minha máquina local para realizar operações básicas ,  para compreender como funciona a **integração** e **consumo** do Web Service em `C#` e nas outras `linguagens de programação`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Já tenho meus métodos para realizar operações CRUD prontos em uma
>   classe . que foram usados em uma aplicação Windows Forms

Você pode usar sim, só chama-los dentro de um método do web services.

> Pelo que entendi posso publicar Web Service utilizando IIS , assim
>   qualquer dispositivo que tenha meu endereço usando uma rede local pode
>   acessar meu Web Service.

Sim, você pode publicar no `IIS`, se sua rede estive acessível pelo dispositivo ele vai se conectar com seu web services normalmente.

> Com um projeto com os métodos do tipo [WebMethod] devidamente
>   configurados vou poder usar os métodos em qualquer linguagem de
>   programação ?

O ideal é que seja no que você tem mais conhecimento, mas pode sim ser feito em outras linguagem.

> Tenho conhecimento vago sobre web services , mas pelo o que eu entendi
>   que o objetivo principal seria a integração das informações .

[Web service](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) é uma solução utilizada na integração de sistemas e na comunicação entre aplicações diferentes

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using WebServiceRohr.Classes.Banco;
using RohrLib.Classes;
using WebServiceRohr.Classes;
using RohrApp.Classes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Description = "Web Service to Work with the Mobile Application", Namespace = "www.seusite.com.br")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class MobileWebService1 : WebServiceBase
    {

        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod()]
        public void MeuMetodo(Int64 id, String Nome)
        {
            using (var DBCtx = new RohrdbContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Aqui eu uso entity framework .... 
                    // faça suas alterações de acordo com suas classes...
                    var Tabela = DBCtx.SuaTabela
                        .Where(O => O.id == id)
                        .ToList();


                    // se precisar retornar dados com json
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                    string RespJson = js.Serialize(Tabela);
                    writeJsonData(RespJson);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        protected void writeJsonData(string s)
        {
            HttpContext context = this.Context;
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            byte[] b = response.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(s);
            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", b.Length.ToString());
            response.BinaryWrite(b);
            try
            {
                this.Context.Response.Flush();
                this.Context.Response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
}
```

classe base para conexões

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using RohrLib.Classes;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebServiceRohr.Classes
{
    public class WebServiceBase : WebService
    {
        private Int32 m_VSParams = 0;

        StateBag ViewState = new System.Web.UI.StateBag();

        // Create a new VSParam with a unique name
        public ViewstateParam<T> CreateParam<T>()
        {
            m_VSParams++;
            return new ViewstateParam<T>(ViewState, "VSP__" + m_VSParams.ToString());
        }

        // Usado nos diversos DBConn
        protected ConnectionStringSettings ConnString
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"];
            }
        }

        protected String ConnString_
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"]);
            }
        }

        private DBConnection m_DBConn = null;
        public DBConnection DBConn
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_DBConn == null)
                    m_DBConn = new DBConnection(ConnString.ConnectionString);
                return m_DBConn;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ! depois reparei fiquei enrolando muito , devia ter peguntado só se meu projeto ASP.NET Web Service Aplication poderia ser consumido em outra linguagem, mesmo assim muito obrigado pela resposta =D +1 .

Comment: Sim, pode ser consumido sim.