# Criar serviço Web que receba strings

Tags: c#, web-service

Tenho que criar um `serviço web`, que nesse serviço irá receber duas `Strings`, um numero de telefone e uma mensagem, que devesa ser "colado" em um `C#` que eu tenho que disparará uma mensagem..

Ou seja, através de outro app que tenho seria enviado duas `strings`, que esse serviço deverá pegar e mandar para o `C#`!

É possível? Se sim, qual a rota ou o caminho para isso?

Comment: deixa eu ver se eu entendi ,  você deseja criar um web service que irá receber um numero de telefone e uma mensagem , e se esses dois estiverem preenchidos corretamente você vai exibir uma mensagem de retorno ? sua pergunta pelo que me parece e bem parecida com a que eu fiz semana passada  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118626/integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-das-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-web-service mas ainda não tive a resposta .

Comment: Você pode criar um web api ou web services para isso.

Comment: Fui respondido em meu tópico , de uma olhada na resposta acredito que o seu objetivo e idêntico ao meu  . http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118626/integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-das-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-web-service/119209#119209

Comment: Isso amigo, mais ou menos isso, mas eu fiz uma ferramenta de disparo de mensagens, que está em C# windows forms, e um outro programa que tenho faria a seguinte ação, ao clicar em um cliente ou um botão que seja, enviaria os dados do cliente (Numero e mensagem) para um serviço e esse serviço mandaria para o C# que dispararia a mensagem...